# Adding vue.js to attribute src

Tags: vue.js

I was trying to add the attribute src with vue.js to the img tag:
`<img v-bind:src="{object.url}"/>`
But for some reason the image is not loading.

Comment: Replace `{object.url}` with `object.url`

Answer (score 0):

Vue's syntax is unlike React's where you use `{object.url}` a lot.
In Vue, this is like this directly

```html
<img :src="object.url" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Vue template, a colon `:` prefixing an html attribute is a shorthand for [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html?redirect=true#v-bind-Shorthand). This allows you to use variables, computed etc. as attribute value instead of static values.

What you are trying is a react way which replace quotes around the attribute value with curly braces. But in Vue you can directly bind the variables without using curly braces.

Hence, It should be **:**

```
<img :src="object.url"/>
```